# Text-Adventure halts unexpectedly after a certain line.

Tags: java, text, switch-statement, maintainability, adventure

I've been working on a text adventure and it all goes smooth until it reaches a line of code. My friend who is very good at programming couldn't figure out what was wrong so he did some tests and still no good outcome. I need your help because his wasn't the greatest. Here is the code so far. Try testing it until you run into the bug where it doesn't accept any more inputs. At first chose ax, then chose help, then yes, then continue, then it stops accepting.

The main class Code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main 
{
public static String thetext;
public static int test;
public static boolean boo;
public static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
public static JFrame window = new JFrame();
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public static JTextArea out = new JTextArea();
public static JTextField in = new JTextField(30);
public static boolean debug_mode = true;

public static void main (String[] a)
{
    window.setSize(640, 480);
    window.setTitle("CtaQuest_A_Text_Adventure");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocation(200, 200);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setFocusable(true);

    out.setEditable(false);
    out.setSize(new Dimension(640, 340));
    out.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 340));

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;

    panel.add(out,constraints);
    constraints.gridy++;

    panel.add(in,constraints);

    window.add(panel);
    out.setSize(new Dimension(640, 340));
    out.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 340));
    out.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 340));


    print("Welcome, My Fellow Nerd! Today, You Will Set Off On A Text Based Adventure, In The Land Of Java.\n");
    print("Before You Set Off On Your Adventure, Let Me Explain What You Will Need To Be Doing.");
    print("To Start, Please Let Me Describe Your Setting...");
    print("The Woods around you glimmer in the sunlight... Water droplets fall off of the leaves \nfrom the morning dew... Birds chirp in the distance. You turn around and \nlook at a stump on the ground.. A Sword and Ax lay \n neatly and orderly next to one another.\n");
    print("Now, for your first task, choose either (Sword), or (Ax). \n (Make sure you use correct spelling. \n and type only what is in the ()'s)");

    switch(InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase()) 
    {
    case "ax":print("Nice choice. You went for Brute Force, instead of agility.\n Your Quest now begins, with an old traveler that needs your help. \n "+'"'+"Young traveler. I need you to help me gather wood with your \n new looking Axe."+'"'+"");
        print("Would you like to (Help)? Or Would you like to (Walk Away)?(Remember, Repeat the options exactly,\n or it wont work)");
        switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
        {
        case "walk away":print("But he is just so charming of an old man, how could you say no? You help him anyway.");
        case "help":print("The old man thanks you and shows you where to start cutting. \n He signals for you to go into a dark part of the forest.\n Do you go into the deep dark forest? (Yes) or (No).");
            switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
            {
            case "no":print("Come on dude, its an old guy that need some wood. Just go and chop some up for him.");
            case "yes":print("You head into the dark Jungle and stumble upon a large vine. \n It swerves and moves freely along the ground. Do you (Attack) or do you (Run)");
                switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                {
                case "run":print("The vine notices you and attacks quickly, cutting your face. \n A tiny bar on the top left of you sceen flashes, and you health drops by 1\n you now have 9/10 Health. You have no choice but to fight back.\n Swinging your sword helplessly, you chop the vines tip off, \n forcing it to fall like a rope, \n smashing the ground. Do you (Go Back) and confront the old man\n,or (Continue) to chop down wood.");
                    switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                    {
                    case "go back":print("You travel slowly, and ohh so cautiously \n back to where you entered the dark part of the forest. You look out of the bushes \n and find that the old man is gone! That sneeky little \n bastard! He must have planned for you to get caught back there. \n But wait, you see a person running away in the distance. Do you: (chase) after the figure, or (Leave) him alone?");
                        switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                        {
                        case "chase":print("you run for about an hour when you realize its a lost cause.\n Man! You should have known that the old man \n wasn't really an old man! Who can run that\n fast and still have wrinkles all over the face!");break;
                        case "leave":print("It was a lost cause anyway. \n You turn around to go find shelter because night is biggening to fall.\n As you turn around a small creature lurks. It turns around and looks at you.\n  Unsheathing your weapon, it copies. Although it is only \n 2 feet tall about you are still scared of what it could do.\n It look just as worried as you do. Suddenly it opens its mouth and talks!\n He says,\n Mister, If you are the violent type of person, i would advise you to join in the colluseum. If you win, you would become the Lord Of All Goblins. Do you (Take) the offer or (Decline)?");break;
                        default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                        }break;
                    case "continue": print("You made a good choice, helping the old man \n before going back. As you chop down a few more branches, you keep your gaurd up, \n watching out for any more monsters. After grabbing the logs and sticks you gathered you travel back\n and relieze that the man is gone! Aww man!\n He made you waste all this time and now he is gone! You look around and find a small rock. \n You chuck it into a tree in frustration. Bad idea.\n The tree starts to move and it looks at you. Do you: (Brace) for impact, or (Attack) first?");
                        switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                        {
                        case "brace":print("The tree winds up his branch, and lashes out at you, striking with great force.\n It knocks you to the ground, and you here a crack. Pain jolts through your arm/n as you try to move it. Without hesitation you run away,/n clenching your broken arm. You find a small cave in the woods and a tall \n mound of dirt. Which do you travel to or into, the (Cave) or the (Dirt) hill?");
                            switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                            {
                            case "cave":print("You cautiously approch the cave.\n Thinking to yourself if there is a monster or not in there\n you take the risk anyway. As you progress into the never ending cave,\n you see a light! It becons in the dark cave and the warmth drags you closer.\n suddenly you hear a voice! Do you, (Continue) or (Turn) around?");break;
                            case "dirt":print("The mound of dirt takes about 30 minutes to climb with your broken arm,\n and at the top it is like a tiny platue. It is a tall mound and the tree looks so puny from up here. You stay the night on the top of the mound...\n\n In the morning you here the birds chirping. You look around at spot a small village!\n Do you (Go) to the village or (Stay) on the mound?");break;
                            default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                            }break;
                        case "attack":print("You run in at high speed,\n the tree looks down at you but before \n it can attack you you strike!\n knocking it to the floor, sliced in half,/n like last nights steak. You gather/n the wood you had chopped and you get the hell out of there./n As you near the point of the forest in which you met the old man you realize/n he is missing! Must have been a set up all along!/n Do you (Search) the forest for him or/n set up a (Fire)?");break;
                        default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                        }break;
                    default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                    }break;
                case "attack":print("You swing you sword at the vine,\n It falls to the ground, dead. Do you \n(Continue) To chop wood, or (Go back)\n And confront the old man?");
                    switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                    {
                    case "go back":print("You travel slowly, and ohh so cautiously \n back to where you entered the dark part of the forest. You look out of the bushes \n and find that the old man is gone! That sneeky little \n bastard! He must have planned for you to get caught back there. \n But wait, you see a person running away in the distance. Do you: (chase) after the figure, or (Leave) him alone?");break;
                    case "continue":print("You made a good choice, helping the old man \n before going back. As you chop down a few more branches, you keep your gaurd up, \n watching out for any more monsters. After grabbing the logs and sticks you gathered you travel back\n and relieze that the man is gone! Aww man!\n He made you waste all this time and now he is gone! You look around and find a small rock. \n You chuck it into a tree in frustration. Bad idea.\n The tree starts to move and it looks at you. Do you: (Brace) for impact, or (Attack) first?");break;
                    default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                    }break;
                default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                }break;
            default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
            }break;
        default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
        }break;
    case "sword":print("Ahh, So you chose Agility over brute force.\n Your Quest now begins,\n with an young traveler that is eager to challenge you. "+'"'+" Race me or face my Wrath!"+'"'+" ");
            print("Would you like to (Race)? Or Would you like to (Face His Wrath)?(Remember, Repeat the options exactly,\n or it wont work)");
        switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
        {
        case "race":print("The Young Traveler gets a head start!\n He sprints all the way down an open path way in the trees.\n Do you follow? (Yes) or (No).");
            switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
            {
            case "no":print("The boy looks like such an easy opponent to race against, So you run after him.");
            case "yes":print("You sprint as fast as you can to catch up, but something catches your foot and you trip.\n You turn around and see a large vine has caught your leg.\n Do you, (Attack) or (Escape)?");
                switch (InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase())
                {
                case "escape":print("The vine just pulls tighter and makes it even harder to escape. \n A small bar on the top of the screen shows your health. It drops by one, leaving you at 9/10 health.\n You pull out your sword.");
                case "attack":print("You swing you sword at the vine,\n chopping it off your leg. It falls to the ground, dead.");break;
                default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
                }break;
            default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
            }

        }break;case "face his wrath":print("The young boy slits your throat and you die instantly. You need to have some common sense in this game.\n You lose. Program Termination...");window.dispose();break;


    default:print("Please, try to complete this and dont fool around.Terminating Program.Teehee!!!");window.dispose();break;
    }   }
private static void print(String string) 
{
    debug("Printing...");
    System.out.println();
    out.setText(out.getText()+"\n");
    boolean threwException = false;
    int exceptions = 0;

    string+=" ";
    for(int prog = 0; prog<string.length(); prog++)
    {
        int wait = 25;

        if(string.charAt(prog) != ' ' || string.charAt(prog-1) != '\n')
        {
            System.out.print(string.charAt(prog));
            out.setText(out.getText()+string.charAt(prog));
        }
        window.repaint();
        switch(string.charAt(prog))
        {
        case ',': wait = 175; break;
        case ' ': wait = 0; break;
        case ':':
        case '-': wait = 135; break;
        case '.': if(string.charAt(prog+1) == ')') {prog++; try{Thread.sleep(25);}catch(Exception e){} System.out.print(string.charAt(prog));
        out.setText(out.getText()+string.charAt(prog)); window.repaint();} wait = 1000; break;
        case '?':
        case '!': wait = 1000; break;
        default: wait=25;
        }
        try 
        {
            string.charAt(prog+2);
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {threwException = true; exceptions++;}
        }
    debug("Done printing.");
    if(threwException)
    {
        debugErr("Threw exception "+exceptions+" time(s).");
    }
    }
public static void debug(String text)
{
    if(debug_mode)
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}

public static void debugErr(String text)
{
    if(debug_mode)
    {
        System.err.println(text);
    }
}
}
```

The inputhandler class Code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class InputHandler
{
static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
public static void waitForEnter()
{
    debug("Waiting for the enter key to be pressed...");
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher()
    {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            return false;
        }
    };
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
    try
    {
        latch.await();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
    debug("Enter key pressed.");
}

public static String getInput()
{
    debug("Getting input...");
    waitForEnter();
    String ret = Main.in.getText();
    Main.out.setText("");
    Main.in.setText("");
    debug("Input obtained.");
    return ret;
}

public static void debug(String text)
{
    if(Main.debug_mode)
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this is one of the most deeply nested case statements in history.

Comment: Is is throwing an error? if so put the stack trace

Comment: The way you are programming your text adventure is very very bad. It should be data-driven (the program is written generically to take data about the adventure and interpret from it what to show to the user and take from the user as actions) not code-driven (the adventure is hard-coded into the program, the logic becomes insanely complex and insanely difficult to follow and add to - like it is right now).

Comment: After yes the choice is run or attack, otherwise you fall into the default which ends the program.

Comment: yes that was a typo on my point, but after you type brace or attack nothing happens, it doesn't even allow you to click enter. it just, sits there and does nothing.

Comment: Mr D , your question is exactly what mine is, why wont it work?

Comment: C'mon who didn't program a text adventure at the beginning or his or her own dev career? :)) +1 for the good times evoked.

Comment: We have to go deeper!

Answer (score 4):

The structure of your program is like a tree, with each node having a description and some decisions branching from it:

```
           / walk away
      / ax - help
start 
      \ sword - race
              \ face his wrath
```

At each step we need a description and a bunch of options

```
class Situation {
    String description;
    Decision[] options;
}
```

Where each decision needs some input and leads to a consequence

```
class Decision {
    String expectedInput;
    Situation consequence;
}
```

Then the logic of playing could be something like this

```
while ( currentSituation.moreToDo() ) {
    currentSituation.describe();
    choice = InputHandler.getInput().toLowerCase();
    currentSituation = currentSituation.consequence(choice);
}
```

The describe method would print the description and loop through the options to display the expected input.

The consequence method would check the choice against the expected input of each option and follow the consequence of the match or display a message and return to the current situation.

The real fun will be getting all your descriptions and options into those objects. It would be best to read from a file that you can change quickly and easily (at least quicker and easier than changing code).

Comment: Hmm, all of the answers sound promising so far so i will try all of them, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is crashing is because your code is badly written :)

Yes, the cause is probably that you have a bug somewhere. But that is just a byproduct of the real problem, which is that your code is too confusing to follow.

What I would suggest doing is writing in a text file something like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "question": "Now, for your first task, choose either (Sword), or (Ax). \n (Make sure you use correct spelling. \n and type only what is in the ()s)",
        "choices": {
            "Sword": 2,
            "Ax": 1
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "question": "Nice choice. You went for Brute Force, instead of agility.\n Your Quest now begins, with an old traveler that needs your help. \n \"Young traveler. I need you to help me gather wood with your \n new looking Axe.\" Would you like to (Help)? Or Would you like to (Walk Away)?(Remember, Repeat the options exactly,\n or it wont work)",
        "choices": {
            "Help": 3,
            "Walk Away": 4
        }
    },
    "3" : ...etc...
}
```

Then figuring out how to get your program to read (This is JSON) and use it to drive the game.

**NOTE:** This is just off the top of my head, so feel free to edit this answer if you can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thank you, i will also try this to see if it changes anything. It will take a while to re-program the game but it just might solve my problem. I also like how you used constructive criticism instead of just criticism.

Answer (score 2):

You are simple arriving at the end of the program. There is not any other `getInput()` or `print` after this:

```
print("You swing you sword at the vine,\n It falls to the ground, dead. Do you \n(Continue) To chop wood, or (Go back)\n And confront the old man?");
```

So the main method exits, but didn't kill the window.

Comment: Im sorry can you explain what you mean in more detail, because what you are saying might just solve my question.

Comment: When you return from the case branch for Attact the program didn't enter in any other `InputHandler.getInput()` it exits all cases and end the main method. You can check writing a `debug("Exiting...");` at the end of main method

Comment: Thank you I will try this, but before i give the correct answer to you i would like to see other people's solutions. This sounds like i good idea though thanks.